# Neovim: module 'lazy' not found

Tags: neovim

I made some mistake when I tried configuring NVIM. I am getting the error below:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/jmawirat/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /Users/jmawirat/.config/nvim/lua/config/lazy.lua:9: module 'lazy' not found:
        no field package.preload['lazy']
        no file './lazy.lua'
        no file '/opt/homebrew/share/luajit-2.1/lazy.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lazy.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lazy/init.lua'
        no file '/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.1/lazy.lua'
        no file '/opt/homebrew/share/lua/5.1/lazy/init.lua'
        no file './lazy.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lazy.so'
        no file '/opt/homebrew/lib/lua/5.1/lazy.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /Users/jmawirat/.config/nvim/lua/config/lazy.lua:9: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /Users/jmawirat/.config/nvim/init.lua:2: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I already tried the following steps:

- Removed and reinstalled Neovim
- Deleted the whole `./config`

Comment: Maybe lazy.nvim is a dependency?

Answer (score -1):

Probably, nvim tried to install lazy but failed, but the files were created. So nvim thinks lazy is installed but it's actually not.

Just delete the `~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/` And then you should be good to go.

If *lazy* folder is not in that directory, you can search for it:

```
$ find / -name *lazy* 2>/dev/null 
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/lazy.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/__pycache__/lazy.cpython-310.pyc
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pytz/lazy.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pytz/__pycache__/lazy.cpython-310.pyc
/home/ensargok/.local/share/nvim/lazy
/home/ensargok/.local/share/nvim/lazy/lazy.nvim
/home/ensargok/git/ensargx/config/nvim/lazy-lock.json
/snap/core22/1033/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pytz/__pycache__/lazy.cpython-310.pyc
/snap/core22/1033/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pytz/lazy.py
/snap/core22/858/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pytz/__pycache__/lazy.cpython-310.pyc
/snap/core22/858/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pytz/lazy.py
/snap/gnome-42-2204/120/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/lazy_wheel.py
/snap/gnome-42-2204/141/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/lazy_wheel.py
/sys/fs/ext4/features/lazy_itable_init
/var/lib/swcatalog/icons/ubuntu-jammy-universe/48x48/clazy_clazy.png
/var/lib/swcatalog/icons/ubuntu-jammy-universe/64x64/clazy_clazy.png
```

And then just delete it: `rm -rf ~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/`